# OleDbDataReader reading command.ExecuteReader();

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

Im try to write a simple Login Form with access DB.
after i press login button its return to code and mark this:

**OleDbDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();**

the connection is successful but when i press login its return.

**mdb name:** users1.mdb
**table name:** DataData

image:
[https://imgur.com/a/gl2Xfga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3RvY.png)

what my problem with my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace CDHW
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Users\RBA\Desktop\123\users1.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                checkConnection.Text = "Connection Successful";
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
            }
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from DataData where User='" + text_Username.Text + "' and Password='" + text_Password.Text + "'";

            OleDbDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
                //count++;
                //
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wellcome to G Tool");
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password is duplicated");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User Name or Password is incorrect");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `command.CommandText = "select * from DataData where User='" + text_Username.Text + "' and Password='" + text_Password.Text + "'";` - there's so many things wrong with that line that it is hard to know where to start... question: is this for a "real" system, or just a local toy? if "real", there are a *lot* of security things we need to cover here...

Comment: I agree with Marc, but looking at your error message. Do you have the column User or the column Password with a type different from text?

Comment: Don't forget to make your code malicious SQL injection proof.   The way you have it written a person can provide a user name that contains addition SQL commands.  

 "select * from DataData where User='" + text_Username.Text + "' and Password='" + text_Password.Text + "'";

Consider what would happen if the user name provided was "Bob'; Delete * from DataData; Select * from DataData where User=''"

Comment: local toy. what worng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: see comments re escaping `User` and `Password`.

The first thing we should consider here is: parameters. Right now, if the username/password contain a range of characters, very bad things can happen; so:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from DataData where [User]=@cn and [Password]=@pw";
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@cn", text_Username.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pw", text_Password.Text));
```

The *next* problem is plain text passwords, but that's a huge area - just... don't ever store passwords as text... ever.

Now, I'm going to assume that the above *doesn't* fix it; if so, you need to check how `User` and `Password` are defined in the database. The error message suggests that one of them isn't very text-like.

There's *also* a lot of `using` etc problems in this code which could lead to odd errors related to "open reader" etc; if possible, I strongly recommend a tool like Dapper, which will make it a lot easier to get this kind of code right. For example:

```
var userIds = connection.Query<string>(
    "select [User] from DataData where [User]=@cn and [Password]=@pw",
    new { cn = text_Username.Text, pw = text_Password.Text }).AsList();
switch(userIds.Count) {
    case 0: // TODO: doesn't exist
    case 1: // TODO: perfect
        break;
    default: // TODO: oops, multiple users
        break;
}
```

Comment: @Steve   [User] and [Password]  is the correct escaping for those.

Comment: Like so? (Edits)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a OleDbDataAdapter with a DataTable instead.

```
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "select * ... ";
    DataTable zDataTable = new DataTable;
    OleDbDataAdapter zDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter;
    zDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
    zDataAdapter.Fill(zDataTable);
    int RecordCount = DataTable.Rows.Count;
```

This way you will not have to iterate through all the records to get the record count.

Comment: There is literally nothing this answer does to even attempt to answer the problems discussed in the question. And... `DataTable` doesn't make the code better

Comment: @Marc Gravell.   Did you even bother to look at OmerAD's included image?  Obviously not because if you did you would see that his problem is that the OleDbDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader(); is throwing an error.  My solution removes his problem and replaces it with code that works.

image: https://imgur.com/a/gl2Xfga

Comment: pretty sure "..." isn't a valid access command - that is the thing that is throwing there error, not the reader code

Comment: Really?  I used a shortner for his SQL and you think that was literal?

Comment: no, you're missing my point; the exception is being raised *by the database engine*, not the .NET code (it is an `OleDbException`, from the image); thus you can change the .NET code all day - it won't make a difference - the *problem* is in the actual command that was issued - the bit that you've glossed over with the `"select * ..."` - so: without addressing the *actual problem*, this will still fail

Comment: @Marc Gravell  "you're missing my point;"  No.  I am ignoring your point because it is irrelevant.  The command "select * from DataData where User='" + text_Username.Text + "' and Password='" + text_Password.Text + "'";  Renders:   "select * from DataData where User='foo' and Password='bar'"  which is a valid Access SQL command.  (and just to be sure - I just tested it)  So... the problem is NOT the actual command that was issued - the bit you mistakenly focused in on thus rendering your complaints here irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry Scott, and I don't expect you to believe this, but: you are wrong. If we get an `OleDbException` from `ExecuteReader`, the problem is the command and only the command. Issuing the exact same command via an adapter will cause the exact same error.

Comment: We are BOTH running in the wrong direction here.  A data type mismatch error in access is cause by quoting numbers or not quoting strings.  My database test has both as strings so both being quoted works.  If I change one to a number, then I duplicate his error.

Answer (score 0):

The using blocks ensure that you database objects are closed and disposed even it there is an error. This insures that unmanaged resources used by these objects are cleaned up.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise the constructor of the command can take the sql statement and the connection.

Use the overload of the Parameters.Add that takes the parameter name and the datatype. This helps keep us aware that the value of the parameter matches the datatype.

Since we used Count in the select statement we can use ExecuteScalar and only bring down a single piece of data rather than the entire record.

Of course in a real application you would NEVER store passwords as plain text.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int RetVal;
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Users\RBA\Desktop\123\users1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Count(*) From DataData Where [user] = @User And [password] = @password;", connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = text_Username.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = text_Password.Text;
                connection.Open();
                RetVal = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        if (RetVal == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Login incorrect");
    }
```

Almost forgot! With the OleDb provider the Parameters must be added to the parameters collection in the same order that they appear in the sql statement. This provider will not match parameter names.